# multi-column follow-mode similar to emacs

Tags: visual-studio-code, emacs, ide, editing, splitview

When I use emacs, I frequently use follow-mode to show one buffer in two columns side by side where the first line of the right hand column is the line after the last line in the left column - basically, two columns like reading two pages side by side.

Is there a way to achieve this in VS code?  I currently open the same file side-by side, and manually scroll the sides to where I want them - but it's nice to have the two kept in sync automatically as I edit and move around.

Comment: In Jetbrains, a plug-in exists for this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8028-joined--wraparound--continuous-tab-scrolling

Comment: Related: [VS Code: How to scroll split panels simultaneously](/q/59187587) and [Synchronise vertical/horizontal scrolling in split view](/q/45325984)